# Rotating Text and Graphic Parts Together in GeoServer SLD Point Layer Label

Tags: qgis, geoserver, sld, coding-style

I am trying to develop an SLD style for GeoServer that represents the label of a point layer based on one of its fields. The label has a text part and a graphic part, which is a square with the length of the text. The problem I have is when I try to make this label rotate according to another field. I can get the text or the graphic part to rotate, but not both. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <NamedLayer>
        <Name>NombreCarreteraAutonomica2erOrden</Name>
        <UserStyle>
          <Title>NombreCarreteraAutonomica2erOrden</Title>
          <FeatureTypeStyle>
            <Rule>
              <TextSymbolizer>
                <Label>
                  <ogc:PropertyName>textname</ogc:PropertyName>
                </Label>
                <Font>
                  <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial Narrow</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="font-style">bold</CssParameter>
                  <CssParameter name="font-charset">0</CssParameter>
                </Font>
                <LabelPlacement>
                  <PointPlacement>
                    <Rotation>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>rotation</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                    </Rotation>
                  </PointPlacement>
                </LabelPlacement>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                <Graphic>
                  <Mark>
                    <WellKnownName>square</WellKnownName>
                    <Fill>
                      <CssParameter name="fill">#e88346</CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                  </Mark>
                  <Rotation>
                      <ogc:Mul>
                        <ogc:PropertyName>rotation</ogc:PropertyName>
                        <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
                      </ogc:Mul>
                    </Rotation>
                  <Size>3</Size>
                </Graphic>
                <VendorOption name="graphic-resize">stretch</VendorOption>
                <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">3 1</VendorOption>
              </TextSymbolizer>
            </Rule>  
          </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
      </NamedLayer>
    </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

[image: Geoserver Layer Preview]

Comment: what happens if you only specify the rotation on the label?

Comment: If I only rotate the label, it rotates correctly. Similarly, if I only rotate the marker, it rotates correctly too. The problem arises when we want to rotate both at the same time.

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.